# Android JNI Global Reference Subtleties

Tags: java, android, c++, garbage-collection, java-native-interface

Ok so given the following steps taken from Cpp

- Use jni to make a dictionary
- Make the jobject of the dictionary returned into a globalref
- Use jni to call a Java method that returns an object **(we will call this object *A*)**
- Add ***A*** to the dictionary WITHOUT making the ref of ***A*** global

What is the lifespan of the ***A***?

My expectations are as follows. The dictionary itself is global and so is protected from garbage collection, when I call the 'Add' method from jni ***A*** is passed 'back into java' and then the dictionary will hold a new reference to it, protecting it too from garbage collection. So I expect ***A*** to last as long as the dictionary (ignoring outside meddling).

Am I on the right track here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> when I call the 'Add' method from jni *A* is passed 'back into java' and then the dictionary will hold a new reference to it, protecting it too from garbage collection.

No. You are conflating two properties of local and global references. A local reference is only valid for the duration of the JNI call it is created in. After that, it's invalid. If you want to use it again in a subsequent JNI call, make it a GlobalRef.

> So I expect *A* to last as long as the dictionary (ignoring outside meddling).

Yes, but the reference itself has become invalid so you can't use it anyway.

Comment: I think I am just explaining myself poorly. I dont want to be able to keep using the local ref to **\*A\***. I want to be able to `Get` the object **\*A\*** back out of the Dictionary (which has a global ref) at a later date.